# Firebase .web App Showing ( Site Not Found )

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting, tailwind-in-js

here is .web link: https://al-realtor.web.app
here is my .firebaseapp link: https://al-realtor.firebaseapp.com

The Web showing me Site not found!
But the FirebaseApp showing everything is all Right

I am Using in my code:

- React
- Tailwind
- FontAwesome
- React Router

and there is no error on my code. It running on netlify and .firebaseapp but not only .web app

Answer (score 2):

**There are usually 3 situations where people are making mistake.**

1. They set up bad public folder when firebase init. This setup is in `firebase.json` file.

```json
"hosting": {
    "public": "dist/public",
    ...
}
```

2. They build project then init and by mistake when init they overwrite `index.html` file.
3. They have server side rendering app. Hosting should redirect requests to a firebase function but what they not know is that every home page request is equal to `example.com/index.html` when hosting has this file it not trigger function and return file. So you need to rename it before deploying.

Comment: I build a build file and select build folder to deploy not public. but not work at all. by the way I am using tailwind.

Comment: @AlSiam Well i can't help you you didn't include any code so i don't know what is going on and no one does.

Comment: Please do Check my post. I have explained it more

Comment: @AlSiam Shift + F5 hard refresh. You have old version of file in browser memory. I got correct site on both of links.

Comment: Thank you very much. But in my country showing Site Not Found. but after hearing from you I turned on my VPN and now its working. Can you please tell me why .web not working on our Country.

Comment: @AlSiam I doubt it is because of your country.

Comment: @AlSiam If it was because your country block `.web.app` you would not get standard Site Not Found html file.

Comment: @AlSiam Hard refresh on mac book is shift + F5 and on windows ctrl +F5. XD If you use chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

Might be late to this but for anyone having this problem. The solution is just to wait. Most likely the google servers near you don't have the latest information about your site. You can usually access the site anyway by using USA VPN.